# How to pass urlname as a variable to url tag in django

Tags: python, django

I have a url defined in `urls.py` of an application

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^group/create', create_group, name='create_group'),
    url(r'^account/create', create_account, name='create_account'),
]
```

context contains

```
{'buttons': {'create_account': {'btn_text': 'Create Account',
                                'secondary': 'Add a new accounting ledger',
                                'url': 'create_account'}}
```

How should I use url in the template.

```
{% for button in buttons %}
    <li class="collection-item">
    <div>
        {% with btn_url=button.url %}
            <a class="btn" href="{% url btn_url %}">{{ button.btn_text }}</a>
        {% endwith %}
        <span class="black-text">{{ button.secondary }}</span>
    </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The above code in the template throws

```
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

How should I pass the url name as a variable into the `url` template tag?
Or if should I some how generate the whole url in my view itself, how should the url be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't think it's possible. I suggest you using `reverse` in your views.py to interpret the url first, then pass the interpreted result into template:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url = reverse('create_account')
# add url to your context
```

According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), `reverse` would have the same result as you use `url` template tag in the template.

Answer (score 0):

In your context, `buttons`  is a dictionary, so looping through `{% for button in buttons %}` will only loop through the keys of the dictionary, i.e. `['btn_text',]`

You might want to loop through the items or values instead:

```
{% for key, value in buttons.items %}
<a class="btn" href="{% url value.btn_url %}">{{ value.btn_text }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

or, if you don't need the keys, you can loop through the values

```
{% for value in button.values %}
<a class="btn" href="{% url value.btn_url %}">{{ value.btn_text }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that dictionaries are not ordered. If you are worried about the order of the items in the dictionary, then use a different data structure like a list or ordered dict.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't try this. I have used `reverse` as @shang suggested.